# Bijection from $f:\mathbb Z \to \mathbb N \times \mathbb N$

Tags: functions

I'm struggling to solve the task of showing a bijective  $f:\mathbb Z \to \mathbb N \times \mathbb N$... Have you any ideas? We currently discus the topic relation/function and inverse. In this context I actually don't get the right approach to the upper question.

Thanks

Eugene

Comment: hmmm...let me think...i still dont fully understand...but maybe it takes some time to flourish :)

Comment: What part do you not understand?

Comment: I just dont get it...and the submission is in 30 min...actually we havent used anything from cantor, so i just thinking of a easer way to show the bijection but tsill thx a lot for your hints

Comment: Have you found out the bijection between $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Yes I thought about to use g: Z to N as g: x to absolute value of x

Comment: However the N x N to N still capture my attention...dont know how to find the function..

Comment: But then $g(-2)=g(2)=2$, so it will not be a bijection.

Comment: Maybe this is easier, you know that prime factorization is unique right? Well define $f^{-1}: \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}:(n_1,n_2) \mapsto (2n_1-1)2^{n_2-1}$. This is a bijection.

Answer (score 2):

First try to show that there is a bijection  $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$, and then show that there is a bijection $g:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$. Then you know that $(f \circ g):\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ is a bijection, because the composition of two bijective functions is again a bijection. This would help you get in the right direction.

Hint bijection $f$:

[image: Bijection $f$]

Extra hint: The inverse is easier to find and if the inverse is bijective then $f$ is bijective too.

Hint bijection $g$:
Distinguish between $x$ is even and $x$ is odd.

Answer (score 0):

Hint for another way of finding bijection $f:\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$:

Notice that every natural number $n\geq1$ can be uniquely expressed as $n=2^km$, where $k$ is natural and $m$ is odd natural.